# order of ajax post requests getting mixed up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a page where the user sends data (via ajax) to a php page, which inputs it to a database. However, occasionally, the requests are getting out of order when I check the database.

Basically, the user inputs events as they occur and hit submit to send it off to the database. Occasionally, the user will record 2 events before sending it, in which case, the 2 events are sent 1 at a time. This case is when they get switched occasionally.

Here is the relevant code.

```
    i = 0;
    while (event[i]) {

        var post_data =  //post data for event[i]

        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "save_event.php",  
            data: post_data,
        }); 

        event.splice(0,1);
    }
```

Event[] is an array containing the events the user is submitting. Each event is an object with various properties. Usually, there is only 1 object in the array, but sometimes there are 2. I removed the part where I do the post_data because it spans 3 lines.

Maybe half of the time that there are 2 events, they get reversed in the database. Is there a way I can eliminate that?  Or does it depend entirely on the length of time it takes the server to process, and occasionally, it will finish the 2nd one before it is done processing the 1st?

Comment: For the responses saying just send all at once, the problem I have with this is that you may still have several change events that can be triggered close to each other (eg form), each with a full but different set of data, these can get out of order and the older data set can override the newer. some id system seems like the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AJAX requests are sent asynchronously and in parallel this will entirely depend on the browser and the processing time of the server. You could add the `async: false` option but this will freeze the browser during the requests as they will no longer be asynchronous.

I would recommend you adding an order column to your database.

```
var post_data = { order: i, ... };
```

Another option would be to send a single AJAX request containing all the data.

Comment: Would it be possible to put in a pause in the script, say at the end of the loop? Like use a setTimeout to delay subsequent requests for .5 second or so? I want the user to still be able to use the page during this time? The user would possibly need to click items immediately, but another request would be at least a couple seconds afterwards.

Comment: The only way to preserve the order is to block because once an asynchronous request is sent you no longer have control.

Comment: Right, I understand the lack of control. What I meant was if I set a slight delay in the end of my loop, would that work to separate the requests slightly? So it would go: request--.5 delay--request. I know it doesn't specifically control the order, but it would separate the two long enough to prevent them from getting switched on server. Would that have any effect on the user?

Comment: If you put a slight delay users might notice it as it will freeze the browser during this delay. Try the `async: false` switch instead.

Comment: OK thank you Darin. I'll check out the async: false switch and see how I like it.

Answer (score 1):

If order matters then either send the sequence number with it and figure it out in the server, or send all the events at the same time.